# Uploading Attched files to temp directory before sending email

Tags: php, file-upload

Trying to upload files attached to the mailing form to the temporary directory on the server before sending email with multiple attachments.

**HTML**

```
        <div class="file-upload-wrapper">
            <label class="file-field" data-max-files="6">
                <input type="file" name="photos" multiple>
                <span>Drag your files here or click to select your files <span>.jpg, .png and .pdf</span></span>
            </label>
            <div class="uploaded-files"></div>
        </div>
```

**Path to directory**

```
$path_to_holding_directory = "/var/www/vhosts/mysite/test.mysite.com/bin/";
```

bin folder has “777” permissions

**PHP Script**

```
    function rearrange( $arr ){
    foreach( $arr as $key => $all ){
        foreach( $all as $i => $val ){
            $new[$i][$key] = $val;
        }
    }
    return $new;
}

if(isset($_FILES['photos']))
{
    $_photos = rearrange($_FILES['photos']);

    foreach($_photos as $file)
    {
        $path_of_uploaded_file = $path_to_holding_directory . $file['name'];
        $tmp_path = $file["tmp_name"];

        if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_path))
        {
            if(!copy($tmp_path,$path_of_uploaded_file))
            {
                $errors .= '\n error while copying the uploaded file';
            }
        }

        print_r($file);

        $message .= $file['name'];
    }
}
```

I get the following array:

```
Array
(
    [name] => gr-1.jpg
    [type] => image/jpeg
    [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpc7s2Ug
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 41253
)
Array
(
    [name] => gr-2.jpg
    [type] => image/jpeg
    [tmp_name] => /tmp/php6qLSeb
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 51475
)
```

I am trying to do this with multiple files, but so far no success. The solution that I am trying to implement was found here [enter link description here](http://form.guide/email-form/php-email-form-attachment.html)

Comment: Whoah! Slow down! You have a PUBLIC directory with 777? move your uploads folder one folder down outside your web root so it cant be accessed by just anyone

Comment: This is just a trial, of course I will move it away from the root completely

Comment: What does your HTML form look like? Please update your question. Also, do you get any errors? What is the current result?

Comment: @ar34z, i have just updated my php, and also added the array that I get from it, so far I cannot save the images into /bin/ directory

Answer (score 0):

Your input field is not marked as an array:
`<input type="file" name="photos" multiple>`

This way it can't hold multiple file values even though you can select it using the file picker. Just name the field as `photos[]`. After posting you'll get an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [photos] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image1.jpg
                    [1] => image2.gif
                )
            // ... more values
        )
)
```

However, I see you're also using a drop target. I don't know what plugin it is, but if you're still facing issues I think you should refer to the creators of the plugin. If it's not a plugin but instead you created it yourself, create a separate question with code to get help.

Comment: I have created the folder outside of root directory and placing uploaded files there, all is working just fine, but the folder has 777 permissions, would this be a potential problem?

Comment: I don't think so, since nobody has direct access to the file via web. You can lower the permissions if apache runs as the same user that owns the file, but that might be problematic on a shared hosting or if you're not the owner of the server.